# "GNOME Tweaks" not in Ubuntu 20.04 Software App

Tags: software-installation, gnome-tweaks

- I can't find the "GNOME Tweaks" app/tool using Ubuntu 20.04 Software app.
- I wan't to use it to customise my Desktop Icons.
- Any help is greatly appreciated.
  Sincerely
  DB

Comment: https://connectwww.com/how-to-install-gnome-tweak-tool-or-tweaks-on-ubuntu/60665/

Comment: GNOME Tweaks is in Universe. You need to enable that repository first.

Comment: As Kulfy has said - https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gnome-tweaks (found in 'universe' so it needs to be enabled) - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be in the Ubuntu Software app from the name "Tweaks". If you can't see it, make sure that *Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)* is enabled.

You can alternatively use the commands (after making sure *universe* is on):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

to get Gnome Tweaks

After your comment,

- If you can't see a Desktop folder in Home, create a new folder in Home and rename it Desktop.
- If the folder doesn't automatically change the icon to the correct one, Type `sudo gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. Change the value of the line that says `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR=` to `"$Home/Desktop"`. So, in the end, the line looks like `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"`

Comment: Strange. No, it is not in my Sofware app.  And when I use the terminal commands you suggest I get the reply "Unable to locate package gnome-tweaks"

Comment: Fixed it by enabling Universe repository (see above) and then using your terminal commands - i.e. sudo apt update / sudo apt install gnome-tweaks.  Thanks everyone for your help and time.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately the saga continues. As indicated above, I have managed to install Tweaks but it exerts no control over the disktop icons - I just can't remove them, despite ticking the correct boxes under Extensions. Furthermore, I do not have a Desktop folder / directory in under my home directory. Weird!

Comment: @Duncan Edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

try just "Tweaks"
or 

sudo apt purge gnome-tweaks && sudo apt clean && sudo apt update && sudo apt install gnome-tweaks

[image: Tweaks]