# Can't remove Desktop icons - using Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: icons

[image]I have posted this question before but the people who were kind enough to answer did not address the problem as posed and the post is now dry - i.e. no-one addressing it. So, I repost the question, hopefully clarifying my problem:

After recently upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 I found icons on my desktop that were not there before - see attached screenshot. When using Gnome-Tweaks I can remove my personal folder and the Wastebasket but the others remain and I don't know how to remove them. I should be most grateful if someone could help. Thank you.[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109785/discussion-on-question-by-duncan-cant-remove-desktop-icons-using-ubuntu-20-04).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you don't have a folder named *Desktop* in `/home/username` make one by, right-clicking in `/home/username` > *New folder* and naming it "Desktop" or by typing `mkdir ~/Desktop` in terminal.
2. Open the *.config* folder in your desktop.
3. Double click on *user-dirs.dirs* files.
4. Change the `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"` line to `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"`
5. Press <kbd>F2</kbd> and type the command `r` to refresh gnome.

Comment: By the way you should also change that `XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/"` line to XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"`

Comment: Many thanks @Sasuke Uchiha - that is perfect!  Just one thing you might want to add is that if there is not a "Desktop" directory in the Home directory, one will need to add it (as described by the reference vanadium gave).  Thanks once again to everyone - I really appreciate your help more than I can convey (I sometimes go for days struggling with a Linux problem and then find you guys give such simple and excellent answers! - Thanks and God bless you all)

Comment: @Duncan Ok, will do that. I didn't add that as I could see the Desktop directory in your screenshot.  Stay safe. A pleasure to help you. It seems I already did [once before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251468/gnome-tweaks-not-in-ubuntu-20-04-software-app)...

Comment: By the way, what is the "HOME/Public" directory for? Thanks.

Comment: @Duncan Read this. https://askubuntu.com/questions/174863/what-purpose-does-the-public-folder-serve